# Join MYSQL tables and sort by two fields?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, sql-order-by

I'm having a problem sorting my tables in MYSQL.

I have my tables setup like this:

### Order_details

- Order_ID
- shipping_cost
- printed

### Product_details

- ID
- Order_ID
- SKU_location

I want to SELECT all orders WHERE printed = FALSE but also sort by the shipping costs and THEN by the SKU_location

How can I join the tables into one query so it sorts by shipping_cost and SKU_location where printed = false?

Answer (score 4):

You can do an implicit JOIN in the following way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Order_details od
JOIN Product_details pd
ON od.Order_ID = pd.Order_ID
WHERE od.printed = FALSE
ORDER BY od.shipping_cost, pd.SKU_location
```

The text following each table renames the table for easy reference in the later parts of the query (i.e. the code "Database.Long_Table_Name ltn" renames the table to "ltn")

Comment: No need to do an implicit join...
SELECT * 
FROM Order_details od 
INNER JOIN Product_details pd 
ON od.Order_ID = pd.Order_ID 
WHERE od.printed = FALSE 
ORDER BY od.shipping_cost, pd.SKU_location

Comment: Seconding Jody's comment. Please don't perpetuate the use of implicit joins.

Comment: @Jody, @Joe : is your suggestion based on the readability of the query? I can see how it is more clear that an expensive operation(join) is being performed by the query that Jody posted.

Comment: I'd say it's debatable that a join is more expensive than a where by default, taking into consideration indexes etc.  For me using explicit joins makes it easier to see what is part of a join and what is part of the actual where clause.  In some cases you can have a join on 2 fields, which in an implicit join is quite easy to miss. Also, implicit OUTER joins have been deprecated in MSSQL 2008.  There's a topic on it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins